# Numbers in Dimension Analysis

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, notation, dimensional-analysis, absolute-units

When I learned [dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis) for the first time, I know that the dimension, for example, of the velocity can be written like this $$[V]=LT^{-1},$$ but in QFT the action for example is dimensionless, this mean $$[S]=1,$$ and 4D volume element have dimension $$[{\rm d}^4x]= -4 ,$$ So The Question:

> What these number represent and how do we get them?

Answer (score 3):

1. OP's inquired dimension/number $D$ is the power of mass dimensions
   $$[Q]=M^D\tag{1} $$
   of a physical quantity $Q$ in units where $c=1=\hbar$.
2. Equivalently, it's the inverse power of length dimensions
   $$[Q]~=~L^{-D}.\tag{2}$$
3. Be aware that the QFT literature often use the shorthand notation
   $$[Q]~=~D\tag{3}$$
   instead of eqs. (1) & (2). This convention (3) probably spurred OP's question in the first place.
4. In QFT such dimensional considerations are e.g. conducted to find the [superficial degree of divergence](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=renormalization&as_epq=superficial+degree+of+divergence) of a Feynman diagram.

Answer (score 2):

If you assume $\hbar = c = 1$ then

- Energy and mass have the same units: $[M] = [E]$. This comes from the $E = m_0c^2$ relation
- Momentum has units of mass, and because of the above, units of energy $[P] = [E]$
- Length has units of distance inverse, since distance times momentum has units of action, which we set to unity with $\hbar = 1$. So $[L] = [P^{-1}] = [E^{-1}]$

You can continue doing the analysis, but in general you can express all in terms of units of energy. That's why you just use a number to denote this. That is,

$$
[E^k]= k
$$

For example, since the units of length are $[E^{-1}]$ we say $[{\rm d}x] = -1$, and $[{\rm d}^4x] = [E^{-4}] = -4$